# iPad: apps deletion problem

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

So, recently I started using an iPad running iOS 10.3.4.

Whenever I delete apps, they *sometimes* do not *really* get deleted, because I can still see an icon with thin lines (picture attached below) with the title of the name of the app. Whenever I try to install the app that has this problem from the App Store, the installation just does not get started.

How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Note: This problem appears after I delete the app using the 'X' (only with some apps).

Comment: Touch and hold (not force-press) on the icon until it starts wiggling. If a small X appears on the icon, tap the X to delete. Does this work for you?

Comment: @IconDaemon
Nope, it does not. This problem appears after I delete the app using the 'X' (only with some apps).

Comment: @IconDaemon
Also, whenever I delete an app that got this bug, the icon disappears. However, after I restart my iPad, the icon appears again. If I delete the app and install it from the App Store, then on the step of installing the app in the App Store, the installation just does not get started.